# How to convert strings of text with pandoc

Tags: linux, pandoc

If my app has a string that's in markdown, `'## Hello'`, can I use pandoc to convert it to HTML directly? I don't want to write it to a file first, but all of the documentation and examples I can find shows files.

I want to do something like this: `pandoc -f markdown -t html '## Hello'`.

Is this possible?

Note: I'm using a [pandoc-bin](https://github.com/toshgoodson/pandoc-bin) which is a node wrapper. I don't think this effects my question as the library seems to wrap the original syntax.

Comment: try `cat markdown| pandoc -f - -t html '## Hello'`  Many programs honor `-` as a command to "read input from std-in". You might not even need that, also try `cat markdown | padoc -t html '## Hello'` . (Kind of unclear about what you're trying to do. Can you edit Q to clarify what is in the file that you wish to avoid creating?) Good luck.

Comment: see revisions to comment above. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter there's no file to begin with. It's just a long string of markdown that's submitted via a web form.

Comment: Did you try my suggestions assuming the source program can be called from the cmd-line? As none of the other 47K Linux followers have chimed in, I still think you'll do better to edit your Q with a testable setup for your Q. Would `echo "## Hello"| pandoc ...` suffice as a test setup? Good luck.

Comment: pandoc does read from STDIN and can write to STDOUT (it's the default, actually) no idea whether your node wrapper supports that... you should ask them...

Answer (score 5):

In Posix-Shell (using Here String):

```sh
$ pandoc -f markdown -t html <<< "# Hello"
<h1 id="hello">Hello</h1>
```

In Bash (using Process Substitution):

```sh
$ pandoc -f markdown -t html <(echo "# Hello")
<h1 id="hello">Hello</h1>
```

### Refer

- [bash - What does <<< mean? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80362/what-does-mean)